# My postman base64 encoding string is throw "MessageTooBig" error

Tags: android, postman

[my error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WIdw.png)

My base64 encoding string is "MessageTooBig" error.

Comment: can you provide code ?

Comment: i am just add form-data inside type key="image" and value="select my image" only.

Comment: Show headers tab (or better paste as text these headers). Propably you have `Content-Type: "application/json"` instead of correct mime-type

Comment: mime-type mean sir?